# Sorting foreign key element in table using {spring boot & Thymeleaf}

Tags: java, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have a sort problem in my UI : [UI problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqEpP.png)

in my case I need to show **Categories.Titre** from **Categorie** table in DB using **Categories.ID** selected from **Produit** table not all elements like the picture show

HTML :

```
<table class="table align-middle mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prix</th>
            <th>Titre</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="produits :${ListeProduit}">
            <th scope="row" th:text="${produits.id}"></th>
            <td th:text="${produits.nom}"></td>
            <td th:text="${produits.prix}"></td>
            <div th:each="categories:${ListeCategorie}">
              <td th:text="${categories.titre}"></td>
            </div>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Modifier</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Supprimer</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Produit Java Class:

```
@Entity
public class Produit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id ;
    private String nom ;
    private String prix ;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Categorie categorie ;
    private int cat_id ;

        /** Default Constructor, getters and setters **/ 
    
    }
```

Categorie Java Class:

```
@Entity
public class Categorie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id ;
    private String titre ;
    private String description ;
    private String image ;

/** Default Constructor, getters and setters **/ 
}
```

so I need to show only **"Titre"** from **Category** table by his **Id** chosen in [add product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEn7n.png) form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understood right, the correct markup would be:

```html
        <tr th:each="produits :${ListeProduit}">
            <th scope="row" th:text="${produits.id}"></th>
            <td th:text="${produits.nom}"></td>
            <td th:text="${produits.prix}"></td>
            <td th:text="${produits.categorie.titre}"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Modifier</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Supprimer</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```